# Слово "неповторимый" является эпитетом?

Tags: стилистика

> Трава, еще не одевшая всю землю,
> сверкала неповторимым блеском юности и
> чистоты.

*Неповторимым* - это эпитет в данном предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, эпитет, а блеск юности и чистоты - метафоры, "одевшая всю землю" - олицетворение (одевает, как человек).

Comment: Написала эпитет "невовторимый блеск". Учитель зачеркнул. Ошибка была в том, что надо было написать эпитет "неповторимый" ( без слова блеск)?

Comment: Во-первых,напишите полностью задание. Если нужно найти все средства выразительности, то здесь более ярки метафора и олицетворение, метафора(скрытое сравнение) сразу бросается в глаза(юность и чистота не блестят в прямом смысле, здесь блестящая трава сравнивается со всем новым и молоденьким, что и правда блестит),а неповторимый блеск - значение скорее не переносное,а просто вторичное, т.е. смысл не в том, что его повторить нельзя, а что он красив в высшей степени, но это тоже эпитет в литературе. Просто от Вас ждали другого ответа - про метафору, которую Вы не увидели.

Comment: И писать нужно было, конечно,только прилагательное

Comment: Про метафору и олицетворение тоже написала. А вот эпитет зачеркнули, пыталась понять в чем моя ошибка

Comment: Возьмите да и спросите, в чём дело. Может, Ваш учитель последователь строгой классификации тропов и считает, что эпитет (строго по правилам) - это прилагательное с переносным смыслом. Дело в том, что некоторые учёные относят к эпитетам все красивые прилагательные, эмоциональные, не разделяя оценочную лексику и эпитеты, а другие строго разделяют. Образ - это перенос свойств одного предмета на другой. Не думала, что в 7 классе так строго разделяют.

Comment: Действительно, стоить уточнить у педагога. Если ошибка, по мнению педагога, заключается в том, что вы написали: ''неповторимый блеск'' вместо ''неповторимый'',то можно было зачеркнуть только ''блеск''. Педагоги тоже ошибаются...

Comment: Учитель объяснила, что неповторимый это не эпитет (почему не объяснила). А как правильно надо писать, когда задание "назвать языковые средства": эпитет (неповторимый блеск) или эпитет (неповторимый)? Будет работа, которую проверять будет не наш учитель.

Comment: Ну, это она у вас  человек не очень эмоциональный, она сочла за прямое значение "нельзя повторить", а здесь в значении "очень красивый". А подчёркивать нужно только прилагательное, а если писать отдельно, то всё словосочетание, но существительное писать в скобках, потому что эпитет только прилагательное.